# Does anyone have any experience connecting Chatgpt's API with 2018 Sage 100?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, sage50

We have a lot of diffuse data in sage 100 and I'd like to have the chatgpt api connect to it and pull insights from years of our company data. This can be done in the Sage Reports function but that's a mess due to some dead or outdated information and for some other reasons.

Does anyone have any experience connecting the two? Looking to use python though I'm an extreme beginner.

Ideally I'd like to have a version of openai that I can train on our datasets. I'm learning as I go now but if someone has advice or has done something similar, I'd really appreciate the help for a small manufacturing company trying to get an edge.